# Where "if" task can be inserted?

Tags: ant, if-statement, task, ant-contrib

I can see, that "if" tasks can be used in "target" root or anywhere, where some action is expected. But can I use it when I'm specifying some parameter?
For example there's ant-javafx task fx:deploy, in which we can declare classpath:

```
<fx:deploy ...>
    <fx:resources>
        <fx:fileset dir="..." ...>
        <fx:fileset dir="..." ...>
    </fx:resources>
</fx:deploy>
```

The question is can I use "if" in that usecase? Example:

```
<fx:deploy ...>
    <fx:resources>
        <if>
          <available file="${lib.dir}" type="dir" />
          <then><fx:fileset dir="${lib.dir}" ...></then>
        </if>
        <fx:fileset dir="..." ...>
    </fx:resources>
</fx:deploy>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, where are you getting your `<if>` tasks?

Are these from [Ant-Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/)? If so, these are tasks and not sub-entities that can be used with in a task.

However, it ***MIGHT*** be possible to define a resource with in an `<if>` statement:

```
<if>
   <avaliable file="${lib.dir}" type="dir"/>
   <then>
       <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" id="lib.fileset">
           <includes name="..."/>
       </fileset>
    </then>
    <else>
        <fileset dir="${foo.dir}" id="lib.fileset">
            <include name="..."/>
        </fileset>
    </else>
</fi>
```

Now you would have a fileset with an id of `lib.fileset` that could be one of two different definitions. You can then use that as part of a sub-entity:

```
<jar destfile="${jar.name}">
    <fileset refid="lib.dir"/>
</jar>
```

I said ***MIGHT*** because I've never tried this, but I really can't see why it wouldn't. I have never used the JavaFX tasks, so I didn't want to give an example with that, but the documentation does say that [`<fx:resources>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference002.htm#CIADIIEI) can use a reference id.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting it from ant-contrib. And yes, fx:resources can use refids. Thanks for your answer, but I just wanted to use if in inner place, this is important here.

Comment: @user1828937 Unfortunately, the `<if>` task can't be used inside another task like that. At least as far as I know. You could give it a try. After all, these aren't standard Ant tasks, so I can't say exactly how they're constructed. The problem has to do with the Java code behind all that Ant magic. WIthout getting into too much detail, there are _resource types_ and _task types_. The `<if>` task is a _task type_ which means it can be used where ever you can use an Ant task. while the _inner place_ stuff are _resource types_.